# Ask user which application to open to view a website in android

Tags: android, android-browser

in my android application I have some buttons that launch the native browser to show the user e.g. the HELP section on my website.

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.xy.com/help"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

So when the user presses the button the browser is launched. But I want a dialog to appear where the user is asked which application he wants to use to view the website.

Is this possible. How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Android, your apps gives the Intent and the OS handles the application selection. If multiple applications are set to handle an http action view intent, then the OS will automatically give the user their options unless they have defined a default.

As far as I know, you can not (or should not) override this behavior.